# How do you change a model name when it shows up in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model name called StoreEntry. Django admin changes it to look like 'Store Entrys'. This is weird. If anything it should be Store entries. Any idea what's going on here and how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model's `Meta` class, set the `verbose_name_plural`. [Docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/options/#ref-models-options).

Comment: The doc link is now dead.